# Silverlight 4 - elevated permission *inside* the browser

Tags: browser, silverlight-4.0, security, full-trust

I know Silverlight 4 can handle elevated permissions outside the browser.  Is there a way to accomplish this **inside** the browser?

I need to make a folder/file upload manager that gives a better user experience than the standard , and I'd like to implement it in Silverlight.

I know Java has an option to gain elevated permissions, but you have to attach a signed certificate to your app.  Does Silverlight 4 have a similar option - to gain elevated permissions by attaching a signed certificate (after warning the user, of course)?

-Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the full-trust option is only available as an OOB application -- ref: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#elevated

Comment: I wish this weren't the case.  I'd love to know if they're going to add certificate-based security into Silverlight in the future.  As it stands, looks like my best option is Java.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in Silverlight 5, but it requires the 'AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser' registry key to be present. See: [How to: Enable Trusted Applications to Run Inside the Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.96%29.aspx)

This makes the feature almost useless: an installer shouldn't modify the key because it's a global value for all apps, so only local intranet applications (where server policies can modify this key) can benefit.

If I'm wrong, please correct me, because it would be great to have trusted in-browser apps :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment - If anyone else has info on this I'd be very interested to hear.  Since I asked this question Silverlight has had a lot of development :)