# Launch Silverlight out of the browser experience based on a url

Tags: silverlight

So the user installs the Silverlight application to their desktop, could this desktop version be launched based on them visiting a url?

http://somesite.com/url?params

And the silverlight application could inspect the parameters of the url it was launched from?

Comment: I don't think so - that would be a **huge** security hole. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530261/silverlight-4-launch-a-trusted-application-into-the-browser

Comment: Is it really a security hole, I am talking about if you visit http://somesite.com/ and install the silverlight app that is running there. Then a day later you click a url http://somesite.com/item12.aspx does it launch your silverlight application and can you access the originating url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only the user can initiate it becoming an out of browser application.

Not to mention that any application which does this without the user expecting it would probably be classed as a virus or at the very least spamming the machine. Not good for your reputation!